# How to add and get data to google datastore on local server?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, cloud

I want to crate a table(Kind) in local datastore and add some data in that table. How can I connect to google datastore on local server?

Comment: You're confusing the relational database concept of a 'table' with the 'kind' in datastore, which is the 'kind' of an entity. An entity in datastore is a single record that is of a particular 'kind'. Datastore is a flat structure. Also please be specific e.g. do you want to do this programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the (standard environment) app engine local development server it emulates the datastore. You can use the code inside your application to create entities via the gae-specific datastore client access libraries: see [Connecting to Cloud Datastore with App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/#connecting_to_datastore_name_short_with_app_engine)

I'm not sure if this is true for Java as well, but the python development server offers in its admin interface an interactive console where one-off calls can be made manually, without modifying the application code.

If you're using the flexible environment or some client library which is not the GAE-specific one(s) mentioned above you probably want to take a look at the [Datastore Emulator](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator). I didn't use it myself, tho.

Answer (score 0):

You can access Cloud Datastore via a client library or using the REST API directly:

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis